# How do I get all comments of a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube

`http://youtube.com/all_comments?v=` stopped working and redirects to `watch?v=...`. A [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/3xqlc4/cant_click_all_comments_anymore/) states that AJAX populator also does not allow to show all the comments when there are multiple thousands of them.

How do I workaround this restriction and view & search all the comments of the particular video?

Comment: The official and maybe the only way is using [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list#parameters). You need to know the basics of programming. I would choose Python.

Comment: You can use this tool I made to download all comments as json https://youtuberandomcomment.com/

Comment: [here is a ruby script that downloads all comments via the API](https://gist.github.com/jaynetics/6f62e7fa79646c1c8a13e34ab76ba85c)

Answer (score 5):

There's a site that gets all the YouTube comments of a video for you and shows them in a similar format to YouTube. **http://youtubextras.com**. It also has a chat box to chat with others and a Top Useful Comments list that comes in handy.

You can use it by adding "xtras" after YouTube in the video url, https://www.youtubextras.com/watch?v=something and it loads it for you.

Comment: Please disclose in your answer if you are affiliated with the product in any way.

Comment: That site gives an error if there are more than 4000 comments on a video.

Comment: This site cannot process unicode text (non-English text)

Comment: When I tried, the site says "Comments are disabled for this video," even though there are comments below the video on Youtube.

Answer (score 5):

[Youtube Comments Suite](https://github.com/mattwright324/youtube-comment-suite) is excellent and can do what you are asking, though if a channel is large it will take a while to pull all of its comments.

Note that you may have to install Java 8 in order to get the program to run.

Comment: oh good grief, Java?!

Answer (score 4):

https://youtuberandomcomment.com/

It will download all comments as json,it might take a while for many comments.

Comment: The UI is a bit subtle, one needs to click `Download all comments` at the top. It gave me a 504 gateway timeout for the vid i tried.